# Bootstrap datatable pagination only showing buttons but not working in Grails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, datatable, pagination

I am using Grails 2.4.2. and bootstrap datatable for Grails. All works fine for datatable in my index page except for pagination. It shows all the related buttons for pagination but don't paginate. Also there is another div where paginate also shown and work but not with datatable ? Here are my attempts below ::

my controller index ::

```
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    respond Audio.list(params), model: [audioInstanceCount: Audio.count()]
}
```

my index view [sorry for uploading the full view,but to express] ::

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="stream">
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'audio.label', default: 'Audio')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable({
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
                });
            } );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="buttons pull-right" style="margin-top: 5px;padding-right: 5px;">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="${createLink(controller: 'dashboard', action: 'homePageStream')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a>
        <g:link class="btn btn-info" action="create"><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link>
    </div>

    <div id="list-audio" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h5><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]"/></h5>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-body">
                <g:if test="${flash.message}">
                    <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
                </g:if>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Short Description</th>
                        <th>Stream Type</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Total Download</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Active</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center;">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <g:each in="${audioInstanceList}" status="i" var="audioInstance">
                        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                            <td>${fieldValue(bean: audioInstance, field: "title")}</td>

                            <td>${fieldValue(bean: audioInstance, field: "shortDesc")}</td>

                            <td>${fieldValue(bean: audioInstance, field: "streamType")}</td>

                            <td align="right">${fieldValue(bean: audioInstance, field: "downloadCount")}</td>

                            %{--<td><g:formatBoolean boolean="${audioInstance.isActive}"/></td>--}%
                            <g:if test="${audioInstance.isActive}">
                                <td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" title="Active"></span></td>
                            </g:if>
                            <g:else>
                                <td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" title="In-Active"></span></td>
                            </g:else>

                            <td align="center">
                                <g:link class="actionLink" action="changeActiveStatus" id="${audioInstance.id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet" title="Change Status"></span></g:link>
                                <g:link class="actionLink" action="edit" id="${audioInstance.id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" title="Edit"></span></g:link>
                                <g:link class="actionLink" action="deleteRow" id="${audioInstance.id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" title="Delete"></span></g:link>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </g:each>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                    <div class="pagination">
                        <g:paginate total="${audioInstanceCount ?: 0}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my pagination image where only shows button but don't work ::

[image: pagination problem]

**EDIT**

here are my javascript >>

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "${createLink(controller:'audio', action:'ajaxAudioList')}"
});
```

here are my controller action >>

```
def ajaxAudioList(){
    def audioInstanceList = Audio.getAll()
    render audioInstanceList as JSON
}
```

here are my table >>

```
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Short Description</th>
            <th>Stream Type</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Total Download</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Active</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>                    
</table>
```

Comment: Two question. How many rows the `Audio` table has? Second - What's in the `stream` layout.

Comment: There are 14 rows and in stream layout just link of css and js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code.

View page..

```
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Short Description</th>
                    <th>Stream Type</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Total Download</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Active</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <g:each in="${dataReturn}" var="dataSet" status="i">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                        <td>${dataSet[0]}</td>
                            <td>${dataSet[1]}</td>
                            <td>${dataSet[2]}</td>
                            <td align="right">${dataSet[3]}</td>
                            <td>${dataSet[4]}</td>

                        <td align="center">
                            <g:link class="actionLink" action="changeActiveStatus" id="${dataSet.DT_RowId}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet" title="Change Status"></span></g:link>
                            <g:link class="actionLink" action="edit" id="${dataSet.DT_RowId}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" title="Edit"></span></g:link>
                            <g:link class="actionLink" action="deleteRow" id="${dataSet.DT_RowId}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" title="Delete"></span></g:link>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Remove pagination div. Pagination will add by dataTable. 
Use the following javascript.

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#example').dataTable({
                    "bAutoWidth": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                    "deferLoading": ${totalCount?:0},
                    "sAjaxSource": "${g.createLink(controller: 'audio',action: 'ajaxAudioList')}",
                    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                        if (aData.DT_RowId == undefined) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        $('td:eq(5)', nRow).html(getActionBtn(nRow, aData));
                        return nRow;
                    },
                    "aoColumns": [
                        null,
                        { "bSortable": false },
                        { "bSortable": false },
                        { "bSortable": false },
                        { "bSortable": false },
                        { "bSortable": false }
                    ]
                });

                $('#example').on('click', 'a.delete-reference', function (e) {
                    var selectRow = $(this).parents('tr');
                    var confirmDel = confirm("Are you sure?");
                    if (confirmDel == true) {
                        var control = this;
                        var referenceId = $(control).attr('referenceId');
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            url: "${g.createLink(controller: 'audio',action: 'deleteRow')}?id=" + referenceId,
                            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                                $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                                alert("Deleted successfully");
                            },
                            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                $('#example').on('click', 'a.inactive-reference', function (e) {
                    //ajax code for Inactive row
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                $('#example').on('click', 'a.edit-reference', function (e) {
                    //ajax code for edit row
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
        });
    function getActionBtn(nRow, aData) {
        var actionButtons = "";
        actionButtons += '<span class="col-md-4 no-padding"><a href="" referenceId="' + aData.DT_RowId + '" class="inactive-reference" title="Change Status">';
        actionButtons += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet"></span></a></span>';
        actionButtons += '<span class="col-md-4 no-padding"><a href="" referenceId="' + aData.DT_RowId + '" class="edit-reference" title="Edit">';
        actionButtons += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></span>';
        actionButtons += '<span class="col-md-4 no-padding"><a href="" referenceId="' + aData.DT_RowId + '" class="delete-reference" title="Delete">';
        actionButtons += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></span>';
        return actionButtons;
}
```

In your controller, you will need two action. The index action will initially load the page with data table ( and 10 row if exist) and a list action that will use for pagination.

```
class AudioController {

def audioService

def index() {
    LinkedHashMap resultMap = audioService.audioPaginateList(params)

    if (!resultMap || resultMap.totalCount == 0) {
        render(view: 'your_view_page', model: [dataReturn: null, totalCount: 0])
        return
    }
    int totalCount = resultMap.totalCount
    render(view: 'your_view_page', model: [dataReturn: resultMap.results, totalCount: totalCount])
}

def ajaxAudioList() {
    LinkedHashMap gridData
    String result
    LinkedHashMap resultMap =audioService.audioPaginateList(params)

    if(!resultMap || resultMap.totalCount== 0){
        gridData = [iTotalRecords: 0, iTotalDisplayRecords: 0, aaData: []]
        result = gridData as JSON
        render result
        return
    }
    int totalCount =resultMap.totalCount
    gridData = [iTotalRecords: totalCount, iTotalDisplayRecords: totalCount, aaData: resultMap.results]
    result = gridData as JSON
    render result
}
//other controller actions
```

Finally add the audioService class in your service

```
class AudioService {
static transactional = false

static final String[] sortColumns = ['id','title','shortDesc']
LinkedHashMap audioPaginateList(GrailsParameterMap params){
    int iDisplayStart = params.iDisplayStart ? params.getInt('iDisplayStart') : 0
    int iDisplayLength = params.iDisplayLength ? params.getInt('iDisplayLength') : 10
    String sSortDir = params.sSortDir_0 ? params.sSortDir_0 : 'desc'
    int iSortingCol = params.iSortCol_0 ? params.getInt('iSortCol_0') : 0
    //Search string, use or logic to all fields that required to include
    String sSearch = params.sSearch ? params.sSearch : null
    if (sSearch) {
        sSearch = "%" + sSearch + "%"
    }
    String sortColumn = getSortColumn(sortColumns,iSortingCol)
    List dataReturns = new ArrayList()
    def c = Audio.createCriteria()
    def results = c.list(max: iDisplayLength, offset: iDisplayStart) {
        and {
            //eq("activeStatus", ActiveStatus.ACTIVE)

        }
        if (sSearch) {
            or {
                ilike('title', sSearch)
                ilike('shortDesc', sSearch)
            }
        }
        order(sortColumn, sSortDir)
    }
    int totalCount = results.totalCount
    if (totalCount > 0) {
        String status
        results.each { Audio audioInstance ->
            if(audioInstance.isActive){
                status = "Active"
            }else {
                status = "Inactive"
            }
            dataReturns.add([DT_RowId: audioInstance.id, 0: audioInstance.title, 1: audioInstance.shortDesc,2: audioInstance.streamType,3: audioInstance.downloadCount, 4: status, 5:''])
        }
    }
    return [totalCount:totalCount,results:dataReturns]
}

public String getSortColumn(String [] sortColumns, int idx){
    if(!sortColumns || sortColumns.length<1)
        return 'id'
    int columnCounts = sortColumns.length
    if(idx>0 && idx<columnCounts){
        return sortColumns[idx]
    }
    return sortColumns[0]
}
```

}

Wish it will help you

Answer (score 1):

I have created an demo of server side datatable for which I have used datatable `v1.10.7`, following is my controller

```
//This action just render the index view
def index(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    render view: 'index'
}

/**
* This action is actually populating the user data in the data table.
* NOTE - datatable need JSON response and list in data key
* I have used projection to get the list of list that is required for
* datatable
**/
def getUsers() {
    String search = params["search[value]"]
    List userList = User.createCriteria().list([max: params.length ?: 10, offset: params.start ?: 0]) {
        if (search) {
            or {
                ilike('firstName', "%${search}%")
                ilike('lastName', "%${search}%")
                ilike('contactNumber', "%${search}%")
            }
        }

        projections {
            property('firstName')
            property('lastName')
            property('age')
            property('contactNumber')
        }
    }

    Map result = [draw: params.draw, recordsTotal: userList.totalCount, recordsFiltered: userList.totalCount, data: userList]
    render result as JSON
}
```

and view -

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Contact Number</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Contact Number</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var goForSearch;
    $(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "${g.createLink(controller: 'user', action: 'getUsers')}"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

NOTE - I have written the code for pagination and search. For sorting you need to add some more code. Use `params['order[0][column]']` and `params["order[0][dir]"]` for sorting.

Comment: thanks for your effort. But 2 things to mention >> `1. search is calling the controller function instead of table & is not working `  & `2. suppose contact number is a property of a parent class , then how to get that in projection cause it's showing in table [object Object]`

Comment: Q1- Search is working. It is calling controller because it is the functionality.

Comment: And for Q2, what is parent, is your domain extending the other (parent) doamin?

Comment: yes, `StreamType streamType` and there is a field in that domain named `typeName`

Comment: What is the data type of `typeName`?

Comment: You have to write the code for searching for parent.

Comment: typeName data type is string & if i block the streamType for search still not woking

Comment: I have tried with parent domain with String property and it is working fine for me. Have a try and if still issue remains then better to ask a new question with your latest code.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue don't know is right or wrong but worked for me. I just skip the pagination in grails cause data-table is doing it. So I have changed the index in controller and it works fine. The changes are as follows ::

```
def audioInstanceList = Audio.getAll()
    [audioInstanceList: audioInstanceList]
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine. But the main issue with this is that you are fetching and sending all the Audio records. And as your Audio records increases, your page loading time also increases. In my opinion, the best solution is use ajax in your data table. Have a look to this page https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/

Comment: @user1690588 if I write the following code in index method , it works . But can you tell me that is it perfect or not >> `params.max = Audio.count()
        params.offset = 0
        def audioInstanceList = Audio.list(max: params.max ?: 10, offset: params.offset ?: 0)
        [audioInstanceList: audioInstanceList]`

Comment: The code you provided is not supporting pagination, it is still fetching all the records.

Comment: can you provide any source code please ? It will be a great help

Comment: Have a look to this [demo](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html). Source code is also provided there.

Comment: @user1690588 thanks for your approach. But may be I am not understanding how to use it. Will you please help me ? I have edited my question with the effort by your link but it only throwing this error at browser console >>  `TypeError: data is undefined`